# Open + Save .exe file in notepad makes it corrupted

Tags: vb.net, exe, corruption

I just published this simple console application that is supposed to show a textbox with the value of a setting called "userID" with value 1001. This works like a charm. Now what I need is to change this value outside the editor, from notepad etc.

When I open the application a lot in there is non-sence (& o!  -å Þþþ,o"  Ü+) etc. but with a quick (ctrl + F) I found the value 1001, and changed this to some other integer. I ran the application again, and it failed, didn't even give any userful error-message. At a point I tried just opening a newly published non-corrupted version of the application, didn't change anything, then saved from notepad, and it were also corrupted. It seems like notepad can't open some characters or something. Do I need to publish the application in some specific text-unicode language or something?

Help much appreciated :) I know it sounds like a stupid application, but it is just a test of concept :)

I use vb.net for this

Comment: You need a hex editor. http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a binary file editor (also called hex editor).  Visual Studio can do that if you open a file in binary mode.
Notepad is a text editor, when you save a binary file with it it will mess things up in all kinds of ways, most obvious being replacing \n with \r\n.
Also everything else about your question is plain scary.  Why are you editing an EXE file??

Answer (score 1):

Notepad is designed to read and write *text* files. Loading an arbitrary binary file (like an executable) into Notepad will probably corrupt the file.

What you're probably looking for is commonly called a ["hex editor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is made for editing text files and does not handle well binary files, i. e. files that have all kinds of non-text or invisible ASCII codes in them.

Manually changing the EXE won't work. You need some external configuration file (like an XML or a simple text file) where you will store the value of this setting, and read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing an Exe have you considered modifying the code file and then running the [compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/380cz5k4.aspx) via [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)